# How to add [Secrets] config for connections in Airflow Helm chart

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

all

I have this configuration to should be in airflow.cfg file

`[secrets] backend = airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend backend_kwargs = {"connections_path": "connections", "variables_path": "variables", "mount_point": "airflow", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8200"}`

but I don't know where in Airflow helm I have to adjust it.

I tried creating separate Configpmap but seems it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the following environmental variable:

- name: "AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND"
- value: "airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend"